# How to redirect user to vue app from django without forcing him to login second time?

Tags: python, django, vue.js, redirect, view

Let's suppose I have a django app based on templates, but i want to make a button that redirects user to admin app made in Vue.js, what is the best way to redirect user to that vue service and not force him to login second time on that vue page?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have control on the Vue app, or at least suggest to have that functionallity implemented:

- The button can contain a a token hidden, `href="myvueapp.com/?some_token_name=xxxxx"`.

In case you don't have any control on the Vue app:

- Nothing to do

And what if I have full control on both, and I want them to share the auth cookies  ?

- You can embeed the Vue app inside a view/url of Django. Once the app is inside django... well you are done.

Actually there are more possibilities, if you will have one domain, two domains, if apps are separated or toguether, if you want to share cookies. But remember, Django can change the settings for admin cookies, you can override django functions to achieve not so common behaviours, you can access/modify the cookies from the Vue app, and cookies are not shared between different domains.